# .Net Standard project type in Visual Studio extension

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am creating an extension that analyses which type of project you have in your solution. And based on the project type it finds the location of generated bytecode. I am not able to find the project type for .Net standard. Any ideas how should I find it?

Comment: .net standard is the definition, not the implementation.

Comment: @DanielA.White so it is the same VSProject type - true ?

Answer (score 2):

Inside .csproj file there is a PropertyGroup element with TargetFramework/TargetFrameworks element containing targets.

Example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.3;netcoreapp1.1;net46</TargetFrameworks>
```

As you can see, "netstandard1.3" is specified here. It is the same as the name of the folder to which MSBuild builds.